# How to use render layers with different sample counts?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, render-layers

Is there a way to use render layers with different sample counts? For instance if I want to render a character with 256 samples but an object in the background with only 64 samples? I cannot find any sample settings in the properties of the file output node nor can I find any node in the compositor that lets me control to sample count.
[image: Compositor]

Answer (score 0):

In the *View Layer Properties* there are *Override* settings. You can either render all objects with the same material specified there (usually used for clay renders of a scene), but you can also set a *Samples* value there. The default 0 means, use the scene settings. Any other value will use this for the current view layer. So you can set multiple different sample settings for different view layers.

[image: samples override]